# Recursive struct definitions in Solidity (Creating Linked Lists)

Tags: recursion, struct, linked-list, solidity

I'm trained mostly in Java so this has never really been an issue for me, but I'm trying to create a linked list in Solidity for a smart contract I am working on. In it, I am using a struct written as such:

```
struct Node {
    address addr; 
    Node _next;
    Node prev;
}
```

While I'm still working out the kinks on whether it's worth it to keep it as a single or doubly linked list, the main issue is that I have a recursive struct definition problem by referencing a Node struct inside my Node struct. I am a little unsure of what my alternatives are. Is this just a limitation of the language? I read [this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/how-to-create-a-data-structure-in-solidity-with-no-limits-on-size), but I couldn't really tell if the answer given was anything more than "it depends".

Thanks for any feedback; let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (double linked list):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract LinkedList {

    struct Node {       
        string data;
        uint pointPrevNode;
        uint pointNextNode; 
    }

    mapping(uint => Node) public nodes;
    uint public nodeNumber = 0;
    uint public count = 1;

    function setData(string _data) public {
        nodes[count].data = _data;
        assignPointers(count);  
    }

    function assignPointers(uint _count) internal {
        nodes[nodeNumber].pointNextNode = _count;
        nodes[_count].pointPrevNode = nodeNumber;
        nodeNumber = _count;
        count++;
    }

}
```